# How can I allow non admin users to edit the menu settings for a node?

Tags: 6, routes, users

How can I set a "Menu settings" field to be available to non admin roles in the permissions page?

Here's an image to clarify what I am trying to allow select roles to edit when creating a new node of a specific content type.

[image]

I need to allow editors etc to adjust the menu settings but can't find the appropriate permission.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to do this?

Comment: Have you try what am I post.

Comment: I haven't had a chance yet but had  a quick look and wasn't able to enable "Bypass content access control" so i need to look further into this. Thanks. I will report back when I get a chance.

Comment: Can anyone advise what may have attracted a down vote for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not advise using the first answer since that is a **very** heavy-handed approach, and the permissions page item 'Bypass content access control' gives a clear warning right below it:

> View, edit and delete all content regardless of permission restrictions. Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.

The better way to go about this is to use the [menu_admin_per_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_admin_per_menu) module. Note that to use this your users would need access to the Management menu. You can also tame that menu's options by using the [config_perms](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_perms%20module) module. The two work well together. This way, certain roles can be set to have access only to particular menus so they can create new menu items, or move them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Goto to the Permission tab & provide the below permissions :

> 1. Bypass content access control
> 2. Administer menus and menu items